# exported classes in compiled wasm class don't appear as functions to javascript in the browser

Tags: javascript, webassembly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
    <body>
        HTML page I created for my WebAssembly module.
        <script>
        const importObject = {
        env: {
                memory:new WebAssembly.Memory({initial:1,maximum:10}),
                __memory_base: 0,
                __table_base: 0,
             }
        };
        WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("x2.wasm"),importObject).then(result => {
        
       
        const value = result.instance.exports._inc(17);
        console.log(value.toString());
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The cpp file get compiled into wasm without any warnings.
But when the script downloads the wasm module, it does not 'see' the exported functions as functions:

Here's the error shown in the browser console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result.instance.exports._inc is not a function
```

What am i missing?
side note- emscripten was included in the source cpp file too.

```
#include<emscripten>
int inc(int a)
{
    return ++a;
}
```

this is the cpp source file. As you will see i just started learning.

compiler flags:

```
em++ x2.cpp -s SIDE_MODULE=2 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_inc'] -O1 -o x2.wasm
```

Comment: Can you post the cpp file and how you compile it, please?

Comment: You can print in the console.log the 'result' and immediately see if that function is exported or not.

Comment: @Bergi : I just updated the post

Comment: @kalwalt: I will try this one more time

Comment: @harsh82 you should wrap your .cpp function inside an extern "C" call, and also there are other errors as i can see, I will post a detailed answer maybe tomorrow if i have time.

Comment: @kalwalt I will get right on that. Thank you.

Comment: @kalwalt i have tried Module.ccall() . Not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: @kalwalt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm describes your suggestion too, I think. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use that method along with `ccall` for C functions. If you prefer to expose classes in wasm interface you should use [Embind for classes](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#classes)